# Dibujar dinámicamente una imagen en canvas por medio de una URL

Tags: javascript

**Editado**

He intentado ésto:

```
function cargar() {


            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {


            // mainCtx.drawImage(this, this.x - this.size, this.y - this.size, 2 * this.size, 2 * this.size);

            };
            window.chile = true;
window.dataURL=document.getElementById('cargar').value;
            imageObj.src = dataURL;

          }

var hats = {

yt9: new Image();

}

hats.yt9.src = window.dataURL;
```

Luego en una funcion 'draw'  donde se dibuja todo:

```
if (window.chile) {
                         mainCtx.save();
               mainCtx.globalAlpha = 1;
                 mainCtx.drawImage(hats.yt9, this.x - this.size, this.y - this.size, 2 * this.size, 2 * this.size);
                 mainCtx.restore();

}
```

Ver el codigo completo [aquí](http://ogar.pw/js/mt6a.js).

**Edit**: Me acabo de fijar que el `imageObj` esta de más..

Comment: proba con loadedSkins[skin].attr('src', 'srcImage.jpg'); .

Comment: me refiero que el usuario carge la imagen en un input, he buscado como loco y solo encuentro para Img , no encuentro para src canvas !!

Comment: tienes 6 medallas, revise tu historial de preguntas y note que **no aceptas ninguna de las respuestas**, asi no funciona esta comunidad.

Comment: Si ya he aprendido como funciona @x-rw

Answer (score 0):

**funciona insertando la url en el input y luego dandole doble click en el input**

```js
function cargar() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            };
var dataURL=document.getElementById('cargar').value;
            imageObj.src = dataURL;
          }

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("cargar").addEventListener("dblclick", cargar);
}
```

```html
    

    <input type="text" id="cargar"/>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500">ho</canvas>
```

Comment: x-rw , muchas gracias pero me explique mal , no quiero que carga un archivo de su pc , sino una url

Comment: hey? , podrias ayudarme?

Comment: @EduardoCampos eso intento, estoy probando algunas cosas

Comment: muchas gracias =)

Comment: @EduardoCampos no funciona por que tiene ser base 64, revisa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590965/uploading-canvas-image-data-to-the-server

Comment: lol , no puedes ayudarme tu? :c

Comment: @EduardoCampos no se cual era el error, pero al final funciono!!!

Comment: oh , intentare me podrias ayudar un poquitin a ajustarlo a mi codigo¿?

Comment: editare mi codigo con lo que he hecho y no me funciono

Comment: @EduardoCampos probaste mi ejemplo? funciona

Comment: SI lo probe pero creo que lo estay adaptando mal a mi codigo porque no me sirve

Comment: Me ayudas a adaptarlo al  codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Está bien hacerlo por medio de una URL, pero en mi opinión, es mejor obtener la imagen mediante la URL por AJAX y convertirla a [`Base64`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_codificando_y_decodificando), de tal modo que, aunque la URL se caiga o expire, la imagen permanezca (se supone se guardan los datos de los jugadores en una base de datos).

**Ejemplo**

```js
let avatarInput = document.getElementById('avatar-url');
let avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
let ctx = avatar.getContext('2d');

avatarInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      let hRatio = avatar.width  / image.width;
      let vRatio =  avatar.height / image.height;
      let ratio  = Math.min ( hRatio, vRatio );
      let centerX = (avatar.width - image.width * ratio ) / 2;
      let centerY = (avatar.height - image.height * ratio ) / 2
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, centerX, centerY, image.width * ratio, image.height * ratio);
    }
    
    let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('GET', avatarInput.value);
    http.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    
    http.onload = function () {
      if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
       let blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'image/png' });
     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function () {
          image.src = reader.result;
        }
      }
    }
    http.send();
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');


body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #3498db;
  text-align: center;
}

.control {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.09) inset;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.control:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0,100,250,.6);
  outline: none;
}

#avatar {
  background-size: cover;
  border: 3px dashed #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>Choose your avatar</h3>
<canvas id="avatar" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
<input type="url" id="avatar-url" class="control" placeholder="Ingresa la URL de tu avatar">
```

La propiedad [`result`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result) de [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) almacena el resultado de la conversión a Base64, en este caso, desde un [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob). Ese Base64 puedes guardarlo en la base de datos para que la imagen esté siempre relacionada con dicho usuario.

---

**Nota:** el código usado en el escalado de la imagen en canvas está basado en [ésta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23105310) de SOen.

Comment: Nota: para que la imagen se muestre es necesario dar Enter sobre el input luego de poner la URL de la imagen.

Comment: Guz vee mi nuevo editado , nose cual es el problema